# MS Detours detoured function not being called

Tags: c++, winapi, kernel32, detours

I'm working with MS detours 4.0, compiled in VS2005 on Windows 10 (Updating an older application).

I'm trying to detour the WriteProfileStringA function normally found in the kernel32.dll with a DLL injection.

The DLL injects just fine, I can debug the target process and can step through the detouring functions.
DetourTransactionBegin, DetourUpdateThread, DetourAttach and DetourTransactionCommit all pass with flying colours returning 0 each time.

```
typedef  BOOL (__stdcall * WriteProfileStringAType)(CHAR *,LPCSTR,LPCSTR);

static WriteProfileStringAType OriginalWriteProfileStringA = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI DetouredWriteProfileStringA(CHAR * lpAppName,
  LPCSTR lpKeyName,
  LPCSTR lpString)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("c:\\temp\\testdetour.txt","w");
    fprintf(file,"DetouredWriteProfileStringA");
    fclose(file);
    return OriginalWriteProfileStringA(lpAppName,lpKeyName, lpString);
}


...
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID reserved)
{
    if (DetourIsHelperProcess()) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
...
                        DetourTransactionBegin();
                        long update = DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
                        OriginalWriteProfileStringA = (WriteProfileStringAType)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"),
                            "WriteProfileStringA");
                        long attach = DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)OriginalWriteProfileStringA, DetouredWriteProfileStringA);
                        long commit = DetourTransactionCommit();

...

    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)OriginalWriteProfileStringA, DetouredWriteProfileStringA);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

BUT when the target application calls the WriteProfileStringA function, the registry is updated but the detour function is never called, break points are ignored and the testdetour.txt isn't created in the c:\temp directory(which does exist)...

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are you SURE the target process is actually calling `WriteProfileStringA`, and not `WriteProfileStringW`, or even Registry functions directly? Also, your use of `GetCurrentThread()` is a little suspicious to me. If you are using a remote thread to inject your DLL, then `GetCurrentThread()` will be your remote thread, not the app's main thread (or other worker threads).

Comment: @RemyLebeau may have a point here. Windows likes to call the Unicode varients of their ascii compliant functions.

Comment: Most `A` functions simply call the `W` functions internally. So try hooking `WriteProfileStringW` instead so that you can catch both functions at the same time. Another possibility - is the target process maybe calling `WritePrivateProfileStringA` instead of `WriteProfileStringA`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau So no luck with `WriteProfileStringW` either.  I do have the source code for the target process and it calls WriteProfileString using the macro and the project is setup as Multibyte so logically it does call the A version... unless I'm missing something

Comment: There are many question on SO about hooks not working after a successful `DetourAttach()`. You are just going to have to debug the code to verify that `DetourTransactionCommit()` is actually altering the `WriteProfileStringA` function's prologue to jump into your hook. Sounds like it is not. Also, do you have the same problem if you use `DetourAttach((PVOID*)&OriginalWriteProfileStringA, ...);` instead?

Comment: So I debugged the Commit call and watched the memory around the function address and it does change which is good news BUT I let the program run then paused it and checked again, the jump had changed again it was neither the original value nor the new value...  Perhaps the pesky antivirus(ESET) is up to something or does Win10 have some type of defense mechanism now?